# How to convert SOAP web service large JSON string response to JSON object?

Tags: java, android, json, web-services, soap

I want to convert data from JSON string sent by SOAP web service to JSON object in an Android application. The code I wrote works fine for small JSON strings sent by server. **The problem is when server sends a large string , the result string gets cut**. I appreciate any suggestion or workaround solution.
Here is the code:

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(SoapRequestHelper... params) {

    SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    soapEnvelope.dotNet = true;
    soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(params[0].getRequest());

    HttpTransportSE httpTransportSE = new HttpTransportSE(params[0].getUrl());
    try {
        httpTransportSE.call(params[0].getSoapAction(), soapEnvelope);
        String result = soapEnvelope.bodyIn.toString();
        return result;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/google/gson https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson These are the two json parse libraries I am familiar with. Have you included either in your gradle?

Comment: The server response is a JSON string which gets cut when the string is large and I lose part of the response. I'm looking for a way to prevent the response from losing data or convert the soapEnvelope object directly to JSON.

Comment: I didn't quite understand your question... the server sends the data but the parser fails to parse the entirety of the response, or are the data truncated from the server and the client never has the chance to see them?

Comment: The server sends data as a JSON string, I get that string and put it in the result, this part works fine.I can even parse the data successfully when the JSON string sent by the server is a small string, the problem rises when the JSON string sent by the server is large, then the result string I receive is not  a complete JSON and it loses some data therefore I can not parse it as JSON object. I wonder if soapEnvelope.bodyIn can get entire data even if it's too large?

Comment: I have a windows app which does the same job perfectly therefore I know that the server doesn't send corrupted data.